# Why can't I get the jQuery jGrowl or Sliding Message library working?

Tags: 7, javascript

So I have tried two different methods to get a dismissable message to slide onto the screen, and neither seems to do anything:

**[jQuery Sliding Messages](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/jquery-sliding-message) Method**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/libraries/jquery-sliding-message/jquery.slidingmessage.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.flyoutMessage = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var options = {id: 'message_from_top',
                     position: 'right',
                     size: 300,
                     backgroundColor: 'red',
                     delay: 1500,
                     speed: 500,
                     fontSize: '30px'
                    };
      $.showMessage("This is with options!", options);
    },
  };
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Note: I had to allow for the use of '$' in jquery-sliding-message.js file by adding it as a parameter to the function() to eliminate an error, but I see no message appear on the screen. There are no error messages either.

**jGrowl Method**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/libraries/jGrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.showAnnouncement = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $.jGrowl("Hello world!", { sticky: true });    
    },
  };
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I checked the source, and there is no "Hello world!" message anywhere to be found. Again, no errors in the console either.

Comment: where does this code live? and have you tried loading the jgrowl js using [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x)?

Comment: The code lives in a block. I know the script works because I can add a hide() function to a div, and that works fine.

Comment: Look at this (DO tutorial)[https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/working-with-javascript-and-jquery] about adding JS to a page. AFAIK it is not recommended to add scripts directly into a page/block but adding it through drupal_add_js and/or theme .info then Drupal gets to properly bring the JS into the system.